# How to conform a ViewController class to a protocol and set it to "self"

Tags: swift, protocols

so I have a swift file with 3 different classes in it

```
import UIKit

class TableRow: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var row: DataRow!
}

class DataRow: UIStackView {
    // addnew stackView

    var allData: [DataCell]!

}


protocol DataCellDelegate {
    func getData(_ personData: [Person])
}
class DataCell: UIStackView {
    weak var delegate: DataCellDelegate?
    var cellData: [Person]?

    let youngerPeople = cellData.filter({$0.age < 16})
    delegate.getData(youngerPeople)
}

 // and I have this VC Class 


import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, DataCellDelegate {

func getData(_ personData: [Person]){

}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: enter code hereIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableRow
    }
}
```

//how do I get to the delegate on `DataCell` and set it as `self` on the 
    //`MyViewController` like this
 // DataCell.delegate = self
   // cos when I put a breakpoint on 1 `getData(_ personData: [Person])` nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

In your view controller you would want:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: indexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableRow
    for dataCell in cell.row.allData { 
        dataCell.delegate = self
    }

    return cell
}
```

Additionally, it looks like you might want to make your `youngerPeople` property lazy:

```swift
let youngerPeople = {
    let data = cellData.filter({$0.age < 16})
    delegate.getData(data)
    return data
}()
```

Comment: One thing to caution you about, the views are going to be re-used as you scroll the table view, it doesn't make 100 cells if thats how many there are, it makes 20 and reuses them as you scroll. As such, making `youngerPeople` a `let` instead of a `var` might give you problems.